# Is id a "root type", or just a type?

Tags: objective-c

Many Objective-C developers, both novice and expert, seem to regard `id` as though it is some magical catch-all type that you can cast an object to and send any old message to without consequence (from the compiler, at least).  But, when one actually looks at the definition of `id`, it's nothing more than a pointer to an `objc_object`.  In this way, it is literally an "Objective-C object," but nothing can "descend" from `id`.  Even NSObject's header doesn't look like:

```
@interface NSObject : id
```

It just reads:

```
@interface NSObject
```

Now, I'm firmly of the belief that `id`'s supposed type neutrality is a side-effect of its implementation, but because there are those that still think otherwise, I've got to ask:

What exactly is the primary function of the `id` type?

Answer (score 10):

`id` is just a generic object pointer, as you've found.  Since it's not a class, nothing can inherit from it.  `NSObject`, strictly speaking, isn't part of the Objective-C language itself, just part of a particular implementation.

`id` is convenient for a language like Objective-C that has such weak typing; it allows you to keep generic object pointers around and send them arbitrary messages.

Comment: I rather like @bbum's definition of `id`.  He described it as "A type that can receive any message," which simulates ObjC's 'neutral type'.

Comment: Nitpicking here but to but absolutely exact, `NSObject` is not a part of a specific Objective-C implementation, but a class of the [Foundation framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/ObjC_classic/_index.html).

Comment: Would it make sense to think of `id` as a `void *` but only for objects?

Comment: Not to cherry pick more, but NSObject is actually a part of the runtime library as of the latest release ;).  @rmaddy I think `void*` would be different, but only because `void*` represents any generic pointer type.  `id` is... a messagable type.  I could just as easily remake `id` by declaring an empty POD C++ class, but that wouldn't be anywhere near as generic as `void*`